# How to answer Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 5 Problem 30.III

Tags: calculus

> Prove: 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2) = \lim_{x\to o^+} f(x)$$

What I have done is:

Say $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2) = L$

That means:

> $\forall\epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta >0$ / if $0<|x|<\delta$ then $|f(x^2)-L| < \epsilon$

What I have to prove is:

> $\forall\epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta >0$ / if $0<x<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$

We already had that $|x| < \delta|$ so, $x < \delta$

I do not know if I have to take one particular x (I guess it is something like that)

I tried $x^2 = y $

So that it would be

> $\forall\epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta >0$ / if $0<y^{1/2}<\delta$ then $|f(y)-L| < \epsilon$

But that $y^{1/2}$ does not help me.

Comment: Please be more specific, what is $f$? Is $f$ a continuous function or not? Is it a multivariable function or not?

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra I looked at this problem in the book and there is nothing about continuity but I think function is singlevariable.

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra it only says to prove it, it is way before the continuity chapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $L = \lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2)$ and if $\epsilon > 0$ is given, there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x^2)-L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x| < \delta$.

Hence if $0 < x < \delta^2$, we have $0 < \sqrt{x} < \delta$, so $|f(x) 
- L| = |f\big(\sqrt{x}^2\big) - L| < \epsilon$. Thus $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x) = L$.

Comment: Doesn't that mean $\lim_{\sqrt{x}\to 0^+} f(x) = L$?

Comment: @Juju9704: Let's recap what we did. Given $\epsilon>0$, we found  $\delta^2$ was the "delta" that worked for this particular limit. We wouldn't say that $\lim_{\sqrt x\to 0^+}f(x) = L$.

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have: if $ \epsilon >0$ , then there ist $\delta >0$ such that $0<|t|<\delta$ implies that $|f(t^2)-L|< \epsilon.$

Now let $0<x< \delta^2$ and $t=\sqrt{x}$, then $0<t< \delta$, hence

$|f(x)-L|=|f(t^2)-L| < \epsilon.$